# VisualSVN server WebUI - customize the browser view

Tags: visualsvn-server

is there a way to adjust/customize the webUI view of VisualSVN Server?

As an example something simple as add a custom button:

[image]

If yes, where is the appropriate file to look at?

Comment: What custom button do you want to add?

Comment: it does not matter for me in first place. Let us say it simply outputs "Hello World" as warning.

Comment: customising the web interface in version 5.1 is unsupported. I.e., you cannot add an arbitrary button. You can contact support@visualsvn.com to suggest a feature (a new button).

Comment: Sad :/. Thank you very much for your answer bahrep. :) I will try and contact the support. Maybe there is something like a "backdoor".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After contacting the SVN support (One of the best support services I experienced so far) they confirmed what bahrep said. Customising the web interface is not supported, but theoretically it is possible to change it on your own risk (Web interface is based on apache).

If there is a feature missing, they add the suggestion to their list for a possible feature.